# Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Mapping.List' to type 'NHibernate.Mapping.IKeyValue'

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Trying to map a relationship in Fluent NHibernate and I'm getting this exception.

Here are the classes

```
public abstract class TaskContainer : DomainObject
{
    public virtual IList<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task : TaskContainer
{
    public virtual TaskContainer TaskContainer { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public static Task Get(int id)
    {
        return Get<Task>(id);
    }
}
```

And the mapping file

```
public class TaskMap : ClassMap<Task>
{
    public TaskMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Description);
        ReferencesAny(x => x.TaskContainer)
            .EntityIdentifierColumn("TaskContainer_Id")
            .EntityTypeColumn("TaskContainerDiscriminator")
            .IdentityType<int>()
            .AddMetaValue<Task>("Task")
        HasMany(x => x.Tasks)
            .KeyColumn("TaskContainer_Id")
            .PropertyRef("Tasks")
            .AsList();
    }
}
```

I've seen other references to this error, but they had to do with implementing `List<T>` instead of `IList<T>`, which I am not doing.

Comment: In which classmap, where the error is?

Comment: It's an inner exception to "An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail", so I'm not getting more information than that. It's being thrown when the configuration is built on the Fluently.Configure() call;

Comment: I still get the exception when I remove the SalesOrder class, so we can assume it is related the Task/TaskContainer relationship. I'll simplify the question to reflect this.

Comment: try initialize IList<Task> Tasks property on constructor in class Task

Answer (score 0):

Try:  .PropertyRef("TaskContainer")

Comment: And since PropertyRef should specify that NHibernate use the mapped ID and type columns for TaskContainer, you should not need   .KeyColumn("TaskContainer_Id")

Comment: When I make this change, I get the exception "collection foreign key mapping has wrong number of columns: CubeNet.Service.DomainObjects.Task.Tasks type: Object"

Comment: I just noticed that the SQL script created by FNH to create the Task table includes both an `Id` column, and a `Task_id` column, which seems like a FK reference to the PK of the same table. That seems odd to me.